# Revisar si el usuario se encuentra en X página y luego direccionar a otra

Tags: javascript

Soy un usuario nuevo en ésto de la programación y mis conocimientos aún son prácticamente nulos, pero acudo aquí para igual aprender más.

El caso es que tengo una cuestión y es que no sabría cómo hacer para que el script verifique si el usuario/visitante se encuentra en una determinada página, éste sea redirigido a otra nada más intentar entrar.

Suponiendo que se encuentre en el índice /index o alguna página /mipagina, pues lo que busco es que si se intenta entrar a esa parte, le mande a otra.

Se me ocurre que podría ser algo cómo

```
if (user.location = XXXXXX) {
Rederidige a otra parte
else {
El codigo deja de ejecutarse.
}
```

¿Tienen alguna idea de cómo lograr algo así?

Comment: mira https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/javascript/javascript-redirect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes conseguir con `window.location`. Te sugiero le eches un vistazo a esta [página](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp). Pero a grandes rasgos puedes hacer algo por el estilo:

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/mi/ruta/privada/') {
    window.location.href = 'https://mipagina.com/la/ruta/a/redireccionar'
} else {
// ejecutar código
}
```

Comment: Oh, entonces es más fácil de lo que esperaba.
Veo que necesito repasar un poco más que me había olvidado de esa manera jeje Gracias por tu tiempo de responderme.